# Research paper: want to reprint an illustration but creator is dead w/no heirs -- how do I get permission?

Tags: academic-writing, copyright

In a research paper, I want to include an illustation from a published monograph, however, to obtain permission from a deceased author with no known living relatives seems to be a problem? The publication was published in 1978.
EB

Comment: I didn't find a tag about obtaining reprint permission.

Answer (score 1):

Is the publisher of the original article still around? Did the author create the illustration, or someone else? If there's no indication of the copyright holder, I would venture to say you'll be OK using the illustration, with a note fully describing its provenance, your search for someone with rights to it, as well as an invitation for any such person to get in touch. 
Also, checking with the publisher or editor of your current article would be wise. They may have standards that cover this situation.
Thomas Goldsmith
Raleigh, N.C.